# How can I create an `Enum` from a list of `String`s or `Symbol`s?

Tags: julia

Given the list of `String`s

```
my_list = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

How do I create the "corresponding" `Enum` object? I am looking for something that looks like

```
@enum MyEnum my_list # does not work
```

that is equivalent to

```
@enum MyEnum Banana Orange Apple
```

Comment: Is the list of strings available at compile time? (I guess not, but if yes, a macro can be written.)

Comment: I think not. But how does one make a string available at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
julia> Main.eval(Meta.parse("@enum MyEnum $(join(my_list, " "))"))

julia> MyEnum
Enum MyEnum:
Banana = 0
Orange = 1
Apple = 2
```

Comment: Or `eval(:(@enum MyEnum $(Symbol.(my_list)...)))`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to traslate the `@enum` macro, and i came to the following:

if you create an Enum of name `MyEnum` and instances a=1,b=2,c=3, the code generated by the `@enum` macro is:

```
primitive type MyEnum <: Base.Enums.Enum{Int32} 32 end 
function MyEnum(x::Integer)
    1<=x<=3 || Base.Enums.enum_argument_error(MyEnum,x)
    return Base.bitcast(MyEnum, convert(Int32, x))
end

Base.Enums.namemap(x::Type{MyEnum}) = Dict{Int32,Symbol}(1=>:a,2=>:b,3=>:c)Base.typemin(x::Type{MyEnum}) = MyEnum(1)
Base.typemax(x::Type{MyEnum}) = MyEnum(3)const a = MyEnum(1)
const b = MyEnum(2)
const c = MyEnum(3)
Base.instances(x::Type{MyEnum}) = (a,b,c)
```

we can proceed as follows, if we have decided the name of the Enum and have a list of `String`s:

```
enum_namemap = Dict(Int32(k)=>v for (k,v) in pairs(Symbol.(my_list)))
const myenum_lo = 1
const myenum_hi = length(enum_namemap)

primitive type MyEnum <: Base.Enums.Enum{Int32} 32 end 
function MyEnum(x::Integer)
    myenum_lo<=x<=myenum_hi || Base.Enums.enum_argument_error(MyEnum,x)
    return Base.bitcast(MyEnum, convert(Int32, x))
end

Base.Enums.namemap(x::Type{MyEnum}) = enum_namemap
Base.typemin(x::Type{MyEnum}) = MyEnum(myenum_lo)
Base.typemax(x::Type{MyEnum}) = MyEnum(myenum_hi)

for (k,v) pairs(enum_namemap)
@eval begin
  const $v= MyEnum($k)
end

const = myenum_instances = ([MyEnum(v) for v in keys(enum_namemap)]...)
@eval begin
  Base.instances(x::Type{MyEnum}) = $myenum_instances 
end
```

With a list of `Symbol`s, the code is easier as there is not any conversion to `Symbol`s

Sadly, i couldnt provide directly the dict or the list of names to the `@enum` macro, that would be the easiest form